# Append file text after last word in Unix

Tags: bash, shell-script

I want to append file text after last word of another file on a UNIX system.

File 1

```
& program executed successfully
```

File 2

```
Hello
World
This is a sample output
```

I want to copy the first two words and paste them after the last word of file 2.

Expected output:

File3

```
Hello
World
This is a sample output & program
```

File2 has a newline character at the end, so when I tried using `cat`, it prints on a new line instead of printing after the last word on the same line. Please suggest a solution using UNIX commands and the bash shell.

Comment: I think you mean you want to copy the first two words, not the first two characters (letters), right?

Comment: Right.. First two words after output keyword

Comment: Executed successfully I don't want to append.. And also there is a space at the end of file 2 after output

Comment: OK, what operating system are you using?

Comment: Unix Operating system

Comment: when you say Unix, you mean Unix and ***not*** Linux, right? Also what shell? Can we assume bash or does this need to be a POSIX shell?

Comment: Unix.. Shell is bash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a funky alternative with `head`, `tail`, `cut` and `paste`:

```bsh
{ head -n -1 file2; ( tail -n 1 file2; cut -d ' ' -f -2 file1) | paste -sd ' ' ;} > file3
```

Or if `head` doesn't have the -1 alternative on your system, it can be replaced with `sed '$d' file2`

Comment: Note that not all implementations of `head` support `-1` as an option-argument to `-n`.

Comment: Correct! I added an alternative. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can select the first 2 words of every line of `file2` with:

```
$ cut -d' ' -f1-2 file1 
& program
```

So you can then use that to do something like this:

```
$ printf '%s %s\n' "$(cat file2)" "$(cut -d' ' -f1-2 file1)" > file3
$ cat file3
Hello
World
This is a sample output & program
```

If your file can have more than one line, and you just want the first one, pass it through `head`:

```
printf '%s %s\n' "$(cat file2)" "$(cut -d' ' -f1-2 file1 | head -n1)"
```

Answer (score 3):

I think that [terdon's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/691230/493832) is good if you know that the second file is short.  If you don't know that it is short, or you know that it is a long enough file to want to avoid reading it into a command substitution, then you may choose to avoid expanding more than the last line of the file in a substitution like that:

```bsh
{
    sed '$d' file2
    printf '%s %s\n' "$( tail -n 1 file2 )" "$( cut -d ' ' -f -2 file1 )"
} >file3
```

This first uses `sed` to output all but the last line from `file2`, and then we use a modified variant of terdon's code to output the last line of `file2` together with the first two space-delimited words from `file1`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a little `ed` program:

```
ed -s file2 << \EOF
$r !cut -d " " -f1,2 file1
-1,.j
w file3
EOF
```

Or, as a one-liner:

```
printf '%s\n' '$r !cut -d " " -f1,2 file1' '-1,.j' 'w file3' | ed -s file2
```

Comment: This is the first time I see `ed` in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

With `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==FNR { append=$1 OFS $2; next }
prev!=""{ print prev } { prev=$0 }
END{ print prev, append }' file1 file2
```

with saving current line into a temporary variable `prev` we delay outputting the lines by one so at the END when we processed all the lines, we append a text from file1 to the last line of the file2.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
f1=open('file1','r')
ext=" ".join(f1.readline().strip().split(' ')[0:2])
f2=open('file2','r')
k=f2.readlines()
k[-1]="{0} {1}".format(k[-1].strip(),ext)
for i in k:
    print i.strip()



output

Hello
World
This is a sample output & program
```